# How can I pass an array as an argument to a function, as well as an object of the same data type of those stored in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, function, arguments

I want to make a function that takes an array and an object as its arguments:

```
public static int myFunction(Object[] array, Object obj) {
     //Stuff
}
```

However, I want to ensure that the data type of `obj` is the same as those stored in `array`. I could throw an exception if they aren't the same by just using `obj instanceof array[0]`, but I was curious if there's a way to specify this in the arguments of the function. I suspect there might be a way to do this with generics, but I'm not experienced enough with them to know for sure. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `public static <E> int myFunction(E[] array, E obj) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want compile-time checking, you can use Generics:

```
public static <T> int myFunction(T[] array, T obj) {
    //Stuff
}
```

You can read up a bit more on Generic Methods in the Java docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: Thank you! From my testing though, this doesn't seem to work for primitive types. Is there any way to make that work?

Comment: For Arrays, you'll need to explicity use the wrapper class rather than primitive, e.g. myFunction(new Integer[0], new Integer(1)); should work

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I figured. Weird that it doesn't work for primitive types though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just test if the class is equal

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] arr = new Object[3];
        arr[0] = "akflj";
    
        char test1 = 'a';
        String test2 = "azdf";
    
        System.out.println(test(arr, test1));
        System.out.println(test(arr, test2));
    }



    public static boolean test(Object[] arr, Object item) {
        if(item.getClass().equals(arr[0].getClass())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

only functions correctly if an item is already in the array